# Trigger break after function has ended

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe I didn't search for the right thing or just didn't write it out correctly, and sorry if this has already been covered.

essentially I have a fully automated script and want to run this script infinitely, essentially I want to repeat the same stuff till I interrupt it.

I have found ways to interrupt it, but then it interrupts wherever it is, which I don't want.

I want to set something like a flag on keypress or whatever and then it continues running the process till it would restart.

```
Do While Until not Active = True
  Call MainFN
Loop
```

TL;DR can I somehow set "Active" with a keypress while the program is running?

edit: "MainFN" runs for quite a while, sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes 30 minutes. hence that's why I want to set active whenever a button has been pressed and then let it finish.

In C++ I'd just use `getasynckeystate` in a separate thread and set the variable. No idea if this can be done here.

Comment: The simplest way would be to check if there is a file with a specific name, like `Dir("c:\temp\Active.txt",vbNormal)<>""`. If it is necessary to interrupt the process, the file is renamed, for example, to "NotActive.txt"

Comment: Add `DoEvents` in the loop after the method call and chose between `While` and `Until` - you cannot have both in the same statement. Also `= True` is redundant.

Comment: as far as i understand doevents, and calling it after mainfn, that would mean it would also only get called once after 30min, id still need to press the key in that exact moment, right?

the edit filename stuff sounds like a good idea, i mean it certainly would work, but not sure if this is the way i want to go

Comment: Yes that is correct but it's the only way to interrupt the current operation and process other messages (e.g. button click, minimize, maximize etc) since VBA is single threaded. See if you can put it within the method keeping in mind that the method will take a bit longer to complete due to the interruptions.

Comment: Perhaps a more elegant option is to check the state of some switch key, for example, CapsLock, on each cycle. [How can Excel vba detect if Caps Lock or Num Lock is on?](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/490068-how-can-excel-vba-detect-if-caps-lock-or-num-lock-is-on.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop runs until ScrollLock is enabled.
Using [this solution](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/490068-how-can-excel-vba-detect-if-caps-lock-or-num-lock-is-on.html).

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Const kCapital = 20
Private Const kNumlock = 144
Private Const kScrollLock = 145

Private Function KeyState(lKey As Long) As Boolean
    KeyState = CBool(GetKeyState(lKey))
End Function

Sub MainFN()
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
End Sub

Sub test1()
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 1
    Do Until KeyState(kScrollLock)
        Debug.Print cnt & " time's do MainFN"
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Call MainFN
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Finished!"
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1 time's do MainFN
2 time's do MainFN
3 time's do MainFN
Finished!
```